# InMemoryUserAdapter keycloack jar in version > 19

Tags: java, keycloak

Good morning,

I want to use org.keycloak.storage.adapter.InMemoryUserAdapter class in maeven project.
Until version 18 it works with the keycloak-server-spi-private library but when I try to switch to version 19 the class is no longer found.
Indeed I think it must be in another package but I have not found which one.

Thanks for your help.

On the documentation, the class still seems to be present though:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/javadocs/org/keycloak/storage/adapter/InMemoryUserAdapter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s now located in keycloak-model-legacy-private-x.x.x.jar it was moved to the legacy package, the package is the same though.